# responsive bootstrap gave me undefined gradient

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I try to make responsive part of this size with bootstrap grid. And always when I do resize of window, so there is made new gradient on right. I tried to find it in developer tools what it is, but there is nothing defined. I'm not sure but I have on more site with same design without bootstrap and there it looks nice when I resize window, but here with bootstrap it's bad. I am not sure if it's really bootstrap but looking for solution, because I really don't have idea.

**Here is code and screen how it looks**

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css);
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titan+One");
body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #7b00e0, #ff006a);
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menu-container {
  background-color: #E59617;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  left: -120px;
  top: -120px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.menu-container.full-menu {
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0 !important;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.full-menu .menu {
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}

.menu {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 160px;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.menu i {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.menu i:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlay.open {
  opacity: .9;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
  
}
.overlay.open li {
  animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: .35s;
  
}
.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}
.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: .45s;
}
.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: .50s;
}
.overlay nav {
  font-size: 3.2em;
  font-family: "Titan One", san-serif;
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}
.overlay ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  height: calc(100% / 4);
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.overlay ul li a:hover, .overlay ul li a:focus, .overlay ul li a:active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}
h1.deti {
  font-size: 5em;
  font-family: "Titan One", san-serif;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 106, 0.4);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2em 1em rgba(255, 0, 106, 0.4);
  color: white;
  margin: 30vh auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 8px 0 rgba(123, 0, 224, 0.4);
  transform: rotate(-12deg);
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}
h1 span {
  color: #ffc901;
}

.blob {
  animation: blobby 4s infinite;
}

.blob2 {
  animation: blobby2 6s infinite;
}

@keyframes blobby {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.08);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes blobby2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.18);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#svg-right {
  display: block;
  fill: #7b00e0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  right: 0;
  width: 60%;
  z-index: -10;
}

#svg-left {
  fill: #ff006a;
  margin: 0;
  width: 60%;
  z-index: -10;
}

@media all and (max-width: 980px) {
  h1.deti {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: "Titan One", san-serif;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  h1.deti {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: "Titan One", san-serif;
  }
  .overlay li {
    font-size: 0.5em;
  }
}

/*komix*/
p {
  color: #fff;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #7b00e0;
  z-index: -99999;
}

h1 span {
  color: #ffc901;
}
h1.mobile {
 visibility: hidden;
}
.mobile {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Kajberšikana</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="mobile"><p class="mobile">Zmizni z mobilu na PC.</p></div>
        <div class="title-deti"><h1 class="deti"><span>Lorem</span><br />Ipsum</h1>
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6"><p>Box 1</p></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6"><p>Box 2</p></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6"><p>Box 2</p></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6"><p>Box 2</p></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6"><p>Box 2</p></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6"><p>Box 2</p></div>
                </div>
<div class="container">
<div class="menu-container" id="toggle">
<a href="#" class="menu" ><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
</div>

  <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
  <nav class="overlay-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Domov</a></li>
      <li><a href="deti.html">Pre deti</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pre dospelých</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>


</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your snippet.

First off, you're supposed to load `bootstrap(.min).js` after jQuery. You also need popper.js for v4.x.

Secondly, you should **never** have a `.container` inside another `.container`.

Third, you want to keep your `.menu-deti` from oversizing `<body>`, using:

```
.title-deti {
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

See it fixed:

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css);
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titan+One");
body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #7b00e0, #ff006a);
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-container {
  background-color: #E59617;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  left: -120px;
  top: -120px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.menu-container.full-menu {
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0 !important;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.full-menu .menu {
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}

.menu {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 160px;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.menu i {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.menu i:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay.open {
  opacity: .9;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay.open li {
  animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: .35s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: .45s;
}

.overlay.open li:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: .50s;
}

.overlay nav {
  font-size: 3.2em;
  font-family: "Titan One", san-serif;
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  height: calc(100% / 4);
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.overlay ul li a:hover,
.overlay ul li a:focus,
.overlay ul li a:active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}

h1.deti {
  font-size: 5em;
  font-family: "Titan One", san-serif;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 106, 0.4);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2em 1em rgba(255, 0, 106, 0.4);
  color: white;
  margin: 30vh auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 8px 0 rgba(123, 0, 224, 0.4);
  transform: rotate(-12deg);
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}

h1 span {
  color: #ffc901;
}

.blob {
  animation: blobby 4s infinite;
}

.blob2 {
  animation: blobby2 6s infinite;
}

@keyframes blobby {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.08);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes blobby2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.18);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#svg-right {
  display: block;
  fill: #7b00e0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  right: 0;
  width: 60%;
  z-index: -10;
}

#svg-left {
  fill: #ff006a;
  margin: 0;
  width: 60%;
  z-index: -10;
}

@media all and (max-width: 980px) {
  h1.deti {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: "Titan One", san-serif;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  h1.deti {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: "Titan One", san-serif;
  }
  .overlay li {
    font-size: 0.5em;
  }
}


/*komix*/

p {
  color: #fff;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #7b00e0;
  z-index: -99999;
}

h1 span {
  color: #ffc901;
}

h1.mobile {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.mobile {
  display: none;
}
.title-deti {
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {h1.deti{width: 100vw;}}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Kajberšikana</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mobile">
    <p class="mobile">Zmizni z mobilu na PC.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="title-deti">
    <h1 class="deti"><span>Lorem</span><br />Ipsum</h1>
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
        <p>Box 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
        <p>Box 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
        <p>Box 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
        <p>Box 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
        <p>Box 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
        <p>Box 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu-container" id="toggle">
      <a href="#" class="menu"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
    <nav class="overlay-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Domov</a></li>
        <li><a href="deti.html">Pre deti</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pre dospelých</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but only in full resolution. When I try to center that text for mobile with queries, so that h1 is getting cut off because of that overflow on resize. @AndreiGheoghiu

Comment: What exactly are you expecting from `width: 800px` on mobile screens, @MiroslavPančík? Why not apply `width:100vw` below a particular width, say... `800px`?

Comment: And by that, I mean: `@media(max-width:800px){h1.deti{width:100vw;}}`. Has to go at the end of your CSS. Won't work if you place it at the start. I added it to the snippet as well.